# SoftwareSerial Bluetooth writing empty strings?

Tags: arduino

Im using an arduino and an hc-06 to communicate with an android. I'm trying to send int values over, but the android says it's receiving empty strings. This is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define rxPin 11                     // define SoftwareSerial rx data pin  
#define txPin 10                     // define SoftwareSerial tx data pin  

#define trigPin 5
#define echoPin 6
SoftwareSerial blueTooth(rxPin, txPin); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  blueTooth.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  int duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  // Added this line
  delayMicroseconds(2); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);

  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29;



   Serial.println(distance);                     
   blueTooth.print ((int)(Serial.read()));          




  delay(200);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is

```
blueTooth.print(distance);
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion, try switching the rx and tx pins. I know I've messed that up a bunch. If you didn't know, the rx from the hc-06 should be defined as the tx pin in software serial and visa versa. Michael Yu's comment is definitely preferred to what you originally had. The other thing I can suggest is posting the android code that receives and parses the incoming data.

My string sending function for arduino:

```
void sendStr(String str){
  char b[2];
  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    String dataSend = str.substring(i,i+1);
    dataSend.toCharArray(b,2);
    bluetooth.print(b);
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Haha yeah, the tx and rx pins mess with me. It turns out nothing is being sent at all to the andriod, it just says it's an empty string because it's not receiving anything. I use MIT app inventor to make the app, the code can be found here: https://gyazo.com/80febfd8461814e85a1e134b5ebbf720. The condition bytesavailabletorecieve>0 returns false. It has worked fine with sending data to the arduino, which makes me think something with the arduino is not working.

Comment: So you have verified that the arduino is able to receive data from the phone over bluetooth?

Comment: Yes, I can turn on an LED from the andriod

Comment: Try just sending a simple message from the arduino to the phone and see if that works. Something like `blueTooth.write(“hello world”);`

Comment: Made no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: What I do know is that the bluetooth can connect and can transmit data one way. Maybe the hc06 isn't able to send data back?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about app inventor and I don't really know what else to recommend for Arduino. Sifting though some old Arduino code that I have successfully used, I was able to a function for sending a string over bluetooth which I have posted in my answer.  What I am doing in this function is splitting the string into bytes and sending them with the SoftwareSerial.print function. Other than that, I am afraid I can't help you much more. Good luck.